# Excel: Conditional formatting of whole row based on column value does not work

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Suppose I have a simple dataset in Excel:

```
Column 1    Column 2
A           1
B           1
C           2
D           4
E           5
F           9
```

[image: P1]

Now I want to mark the whole row with green color, if the value in column 2 is larger than 3. I apply a conditional format with the formula `=$B2>3` applied on range `=$A$1:$B$7` and it does not work:

[image: ex1]

One line where the value is 2 is marked green and one where it is 9 is not marked.

Now I want to mark the row, however only, if the value in column 2 is between 3 and 6. I apply the formula `=AND(3<$B2;$B2<6)` to the same range and it does not work:

[image: ex2]

Nothing is marked green.

Where is my mistake?

**Update**:
I now also tried `=AND(3<$B1;$B1<6)`, but still nothing is marked green?

Comment: For your 1st problem. You apply the wrong formula to the wrong range. Use `=$B1>3` *or* use a different range, e.g. `=$A$2:$B$7`

Comment: The 2nd problem. Same as 1st, apply to a different range or use `=AND($B1>=3,$B1<=6)`

Comment: Oh! I saw comment after posting answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the second one still does not work.

Comment: Why `=AND(3<$B1;$B1<6)` instead of `=AND($B1>=3,$B1<=6)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `=$B2>3` to `=$B1>3` which should work for you.

Your formula start range and apply start range must be same. Otherwise CF will highlight different cells.

Comment: For the second problem I now entered =AND(3<$B1;$B1<6) and it still does not work? Nothing is marked green.

Comment: The problem seems to be somehow connected to the AND condition. If I juse use a single condition it works, but not with AND?

Comment: @PSt As JvdV mentioned `=AND($B1>=3,$B1<=6)` this should work for you.